# How to extract a slice of an array given an element position in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to extract a slice of an array in MongoDB given the position of a certain element (action4 in the example). The sample data is

```
[{name: 'John Doe', actions: ['action1', 'action2', 'action3', 'action4']},
{name: 'Margie Addams', actions: ['action1', 'action2', 'action4', 'action3']},
{name: 'Fer Doughnut', actions: ['action1', 'action4', 'action3', 'action2']},
{name: 'Anthony Peralta', actions: ['action1', 'action2', 'action3', 'action4']},
{name: 'Pete Parker', actions: ['action1', 'action2', 'action3', 'action4']},
{name: 'Josh Dean', actions: ['action4', 'action2', 'action3', 'action1']}]
```

I managed to find the position of `action4` inside the array with an aggregation query like

```
{$indexOfArray: ["$actions", "action4"]}
```

but can't find a way to extract from the beginning of the array to its position.
Any suggestion?

Comment: did you try `$slice`?

Comment: Yes, but I'm relative new to MongoDB and can't find my way to solve it using the operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) and [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) aggregation operators like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      actions: {
        $slice: [
          "$actions",
          {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$actions",
              "action4"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tBi4B4sa9UK)

Comment: Great! What if I would like to include the ```action4``` also?

Comment: This seemed to work!

```db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      actions: {
        $slice: [
          "$actions",
          {
            $sum: [
              {
                $indexOfArray: [
                  "$actions",
                  "action4"
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])```

Comment: @arlugones yes it looks good, https://mongoplayground.net/p/omGKj3uR1Yv . I would be happy if you can also up vote the answer.